# Why does casting a char array to an int pointer and writing to it using the pointer make the data reversed?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I created some simple code to test casting a char array to int pointer.  This works fine as I expected, but when I wrote to the array using the pointer, the data got swapped MSB<-->LSB when I print the c array back out.  Why does this happen?  Is this an OS dependent thing?

```
#include "stdio.h"

const int SIZE = 12;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[]) {
    unsigned char c[SIZE] = {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
    };
    unsigned int * ptr = (unsigned int * ) c;
    int i;

    printf("Int size=%d\n", sizeof(unsigned long));

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++) {
        printf("%X, ", c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(c) / sizeof(unsigned long); i++) { * ptr++ = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++) {
        printf("%X, ", c[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Int size=4
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0,
```

Comment: Aside: you should make up your mind whether `ptr` should be `unsigned int*` or `unsigned long*`.

Comment: you have at least three undefined behaviours due to wrong format specifiers in printf

Comment: I would expect the problem to be related to the 'Endian'ness of the underlying hardware.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your architecture is Little Endian, which means the least significant byte is stored first in memory:

[image]

In your case 0x00000001 is written in the order [0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00].

Comment: This wikipedia drawing always throws me off, as they label the memory from the top to bottom, and at a first look you'll say that 0D lies at the "higher" memory location. +1 btw.

Answer (score 8):

This is caused by [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) of your CPU architecture.  Your architecture seems to be [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) to cause this kind of inversions.

Answer (score 2):

- You are getting confused since, **English language is Big-endian
  annotation**.
- Read from  left to right.

Eg: 0xDead is stored like

```
  0xD      0xE       0xA       0xD
0xADDR  0xADDR+1  0XADDR+2  0xADDR+3
```